# Is there a way to print out text without 'adding' spaces?

Tags: java, nested-loops

I am working on a method that outputs this:

```
**********
*        *
*        *
*  Hello *
*        *
*        *
**********
```

I have a feeling I need to use .substring method but have gotten stuck. A lot of sources have told me to use nested loops and that is what I have done except when I go and try to place my message into the shape an extra space is added naturally caused by the string shifting the star char to the right:

```
***********
*         *
*         *
*  Hello    *
*         *
*         *
***********
```

I'm using java 8. int n is the amount of c characters are placed on the top and bottom of the shape. String message would be hello in this case.

```
public void boxThing(int n, char c, String message) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= (n/2); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == n) {
                    System.out.print(c);
                }
                else if(j == 0 || j == n) {
                    System.out.print(c);
                }
                else if(j==n/2 && i==((n/2)/2)+1){
                    System.out.print(message);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.printf(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for(int i =0; i<=n; i++){
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use `printf` in one place and `print` everywhere else?

Comment: With each iteration of the inner loop you expect one character to be written. However, the message is longer ...

Comment: No true reason. Just happened to use it. As you mentioned it, I changed it in my code because it bothered me. @BoristheSpider

Comment: You need to take the length of the message into account when printing `message`; and, having printed that, you need to increase `j` so it doesn't print the spaces you don't need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the length of the message to j and minus by 1, for example, the word "hello" takes 5 positions. Since j will add 1 on the loop for the word you just have to set j to be the j + message length -1 when it reaches the second else if condition. Refer below.

```java
for(int i = 0; i <= (n/2); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == n) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
        else if (j == 0 || j == n) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
        else if (j == n/2 && i == ((n/2)/2)+1) {
            System.out.print(message);
            j = j + message.length() - 1;
        }
        else {
           System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
    System.out.print(c);
}
```

Comment: You have miss-matching braces `{}`.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there..

What you need to print nothing when the "column" contains the message you have printed.

ie. "Hello" is 5 characters starting from column of index 3.
That means, index 3-7 will already contain "Hello", so, you should not print any characters in between this column.